# onclick method to dynamically created button in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery-mobile package to develop web based mobile application. From a php script I read the button id's from MySQL and send id's to JavaScript method to create a button for it. However I want to add onclick listener also, ofcourse, but I could not manage it.
Any help please.

```
<div data-role="content2" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createButton(n) {
            $('[data-role="page"]').append('<button  data-theme= "b" id="btnInit' + n + '" >' + n + '</button>');// here I want to add onclick listener
        }

    <?php
        include './_fonksiyon.php';
        $query = ("
            SELECT
                tbl_ustmenu.Id AS id,
                tbl_ustmenu.AdiT AS adi
            FROM tbl_ustmenu
            WHERE tbl_ustmenu.Aktif=1
            AND   tbl_ustmenu.UstMenuId=0
            ORDER BY tbl_ustmenu.Sira ASC
                                    ");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $count = 0;
        while ($count < mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            $i = (mysql_result($result,$count, ($id)));
            $count++;
        ?>
            createButton(<?php echo ($i) ; ?>);

        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Consider indenting things ... er, differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the button to a variable first, it's more readable

```
var btn = $('<button  data-theme= "b" id="btnInit' + n + '" >' + n + '</button>');
btn.click(function() {
    alert('here we go');
});
$('[data-role="page"]').append(btn);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is solved by this way. By the way, I want to ask one more thing. "adi" variable in the query returns a string, how can I pass it to myfunction, createButton? I both need to pass integer and a string(id,adi)

Comment: 1. Extend your createButton-function: function createButton(n,adi) {}

2. Extend your php-echo: createButton(<?php echo($i).",".echo($adi); ?>);

Not very familiar with php, maybe you need to reference $adi correctly

Comment: I know that, but javascript does not accept strings as integers. I know I have to remove the quotations in it, but I am not sure how to :) thanks anyway

Comment: Ah, my fault. Try this:

createButton(<?php echo($i).", '".echo($adi)."'"; ?>);

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with PHP. `<?php echo($i.",'".$adi."'"); ?>`

Your JavaScript output (view source) should be `createButton(1, 'adi-string');`

Comment: This one is the correct one;createButton(<?php echo($i.",'".$adi."');"); ?> Thanks for your help again :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `createButton` with the snippet below, or create a separate function using the same snippet.

```
<script type="javascript">
    var button = document.createElement("INPUT");
    button.type = "button";
    button.name = "button";
    button.value = "Click me";
    button.id = "<?php echo $i ?>";
    button.onclick = function() {
        // ...
        // function body
    };
    // you may append it to any element you need
    document.body.appendChild(button);
</script>
```

Comment: I like how you just went native with it :)

Comment: @MoshMage Old school :)

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your button and create a bind on click, like this:

```
$('[data-role="page"]').append('<button  class="mybuttonclass" data-theme= "b" id="btnInit' + n + '" >' + n + '</button>');



$(".mybuttonclass").on("click",function(e){
    //..
});
```

Comment: It stops to create buttons after first one is created. It is solved, thanks anyway